# Can't get variables to work in WPDB UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I've tried all I can but this query will not work. I've tried prepare, adding ' to both variables, adding ' to only the SET variable, using springf, using a formatted string where both values are inserted into %s, nothing works. I've spent the whole night on this and right now I just feel like crying.

This query works when I hard-code the values or paste the dump directly in phpmyadmin.

```
$trans = strval($_POST["trans"]);
$status = strval($_POST["status"]);

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors;
$query = "UPDATE donations SET donation_status='".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' WHERE donation_reference = '".mysql_real_escape_string($trans)."'";

$result = $wpdb->query($query);

$wpdb->print_error;

exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
```

Another funny thing is the query works when I replace the first two lines with hard-coded values, like:

```
$trans = "12345678";
$status = "Transaction Successful";
```

But as long as the values are read from the $_POST variables, the query doesn't work.

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.28 and MySQL 5.5.40.

Please help!

Comment: echo your query and post it and match with static values query what you miss

Comment: check your browser console to ensure that the data is indeed being POSTed. You can also try `isset($_POST["trans"]) ? strval($_POST["trans"]) : "value missing"`

Comment: $_POST definitely contains the correct values, as I'm using $trans and $status to display content later on in the page and that works fine, my only problem is this table update.

Comment: The query from dump is    `UPDATE donations SET donation_status='Transaction Successful' WHERE donation_reference='12345678'` , looks fine to me, just not running

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure $_POST contains what you expect.

Then for added security, use [`wpdb::update()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) method instead of `wpdb::query()`

```
$trans = strval($_POST["trans"]);
$status = strval($_POST["status"]);

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors;
$wdpb->update(
    'donations',
    array( 'dontion_status' => $status ),
    array( 'donation_reference' => $trans ),
);
$wpdb->print_error;

exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
```

Comment: You are missing the point, OP already mentioned that the query works when he uses hard coded values. So its not an issue of `wpdb->update` vs `wpdp->query`. The issue seems to be that `$_POST` doesn't contain the data that it should.

Comment: Yeah I've already tried `$wpdb->update` and it isn't working either, and no error is produced

Comment: @Keezy Well then check $_POST, `die('<pre>' . var_export($_POST,1));`

Comment: @NabilKadimi $_POST is working fine. `array (
  'trans' => '12345678',
  'status' => 'Transaction Successful',
  'amt' => '1000.00',
)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue. Setting variables for the UPDATE and WHERE sections of the query solved it. So, for your code, using the suggested $wdpb->update method, it would be:

```
$status = strval($_POST["status"]);
$trans = strval($_POST["trans"]);

$table_name = 'donations';
$data_update = array( 'dontion_status' => '$status' );
$data_where = array('id' => '$id');

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update($table_name, $data_update, $data_where, array('%s'), array('%d'));

exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
```